# about partial view's path on Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use AspNet MVC 4. I use partial views on my project. I put partial views in shared/partial folder. And I call relating partial page in a view.

[image]

For example, I add _category.cshtml partial view to Views/Categories/Index.cshtml like below.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/partial_leftmenu/_category.cshtml")
```

My question is that, I have to write all path "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/partial_leftmenu/...." for calling any partial view. I try to find a solution for writing this path shortly.

For example, I will define "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/partial_leftmenu" path as a variable, and I write this variable instead of "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/partial_leftmenu" path.  I try this this, but it could not work.(like below)

```
@Html.Partial(partial_path+"/_category.cshtml")
```

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe MVC automatically searches through all files and folders in Views/Shared so I think all you need is:

```
@Html.Partial("_category")
```

Beyond that if you're in a specific area then it searches both main/root views folder and the current areas views folder. If you're trying to access partial from one area while you're currently in another then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can change where MVC searches to include custom folders.  [See here.](http://www.leonamarant.com/2011/02/17/adding-a-custom-directory-to-razor-view-engine-partial-view-locations-in-asp-net-mvc3/)